# Is possible to merge two models/ arrays and show them with *ngFor in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, timeline

Im getting data from a server :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.getAllProjects().subscribe(data =>{
      this.projectshowAll = data.project;

    });
  this.projectteamsService.getAllTeams().subscribe(data =>{
    this.teamshowAll = data.projectteams;
  });
```

and im using **angular-mgl-timeline** package

```
<mgl-timeline  [toggle]="toggle" [alternate]="alternate">
      <mgl-timeline-entry *ngFor="let proj of projectshowAll; let i = index; " (expand)="onExpandEntry($event, i)">
        <mgl-timeline-entry-header  (click)="onHeaderClick($event)">
          <div   class="headerTitle">Project: {{proj.projectname}}</div>
        </mgl-timeline-entry-header>
        <mgl-timeline-entry-content>
          <div class="headerTitle">
            <div>{{proj.projectnumber}}</div>
            <div>{{proj.projectteams}}</div>
            <div>{{proj.createdBy}}</div>
          </div>
        </mgl-timeline-entry-content>
        <mgl-timeline-entry-dot [class]="color ? 'primary' : 'accent'" 
                                [size]="size"
                                (click)="onDotClick($event)"></mgl-timeline-entry-dot>
        <mgl-timeline-entry-side  class="datestyle">Created by: {{proj.createdBy}} At: {{proj.completiondate | date:'MMM dd, yyyy' }} </mgl-timeline-entry-side>
      </mgl-timeline-entry>
    </mgl-timeline>
```

At the moment i can retrieve the array of "projectshowAll" and i want to have both "projectshowAll" + "teamshowAll" and when create a new project or team go in the top of timeline.

[image]

I have searched everything and i cant find anything that works in angular 6,
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what angular-mgl-timeline is, but it appears you are asking how to merge two arrays. Which is pretty straight forward using `Array.prototype.concat()` functions. [Readmore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

If you want to do the array merge in template, you can do this:

```
*ngFor="let proj of projectshowAll.concat(teamshowAll);
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer, this ngFor means that  from "proj" i can get projectsjowAll values and teamshowAll values ? e.g {{proj.projectTitle }} and {{proj.teamTitle}}?

Comment: @ZarkOs, basically it ends up being array of objects. And two types of objects in your case. So, you'll have to worry about which object has which property...but short answer is yes, proj.projectTitle, proj.teamTitle will work for respective objects

Comment: Yeah it works perfect! Thank you mate! Now i have to find a way to show on top of timeline every new "team or project" registration, but thats another story, Cya around :)

Answer (score 0):

> Its pretty easy in TypeScript if you want to merge Array.

```
finalArray = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.getAllProjects().subscribe(data =>{
      this.projectshowAll = data.project;
      this.finalArray.push(...this.projectshowAll);

    });
  this.projectteamsService.getAllTeams().subscribe(data =>{
    this.teamshowAll = data.projectteams;
    this.finalArray.push(...this.teamshowAll);
  });
```

Comment: Hello and thanks, it works  with a console output. any help with the html part ?